# Migrating to Oracle using Corda Enterprise Database Manager Tool Unable to Connect

Tags: oracle12c, enterprise, data-migration, corda

I am using Corda Enterprise 3.1 and trying to move the vault from H2 to Oracle 12c using the Database Migration tool supplied. I have made the changes in the node.conf configuration using values I know work to connect from IntelliJ. The driver is Oracle's ojdbc8.jar that came with Oracle SQL Developer. The connection string is below but with some specifics masked. It doesn't work. Any ideas?

```
dataSourceClassName = oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleDataSource
dataSource.url = "jdbc:oracle:thin:@xxxxx.wellsfargo.com:1539:XXXXXX"
```

Here is the error I get:

> -- 2018-08-07T00:04:55,757Z migration.tool.handleCommand - Exporting the current db migrations ...  Failed to create datasource. Please
>   check that the correct JDBC driver is installed in one of the
>   following folders:
>      - /apps/team/drivers/jdbc
>
> Caused By java.sql.SQLRecoverableException: IO Error: The Network Adapter could
>   not establish the connection

Comment: I made some more progress. There was an error in the host url which I fixed, but now I get an error when it tries to migrate the schema of the "Yo" CorDapp. I am using that as a basic "Hello World" test. The error is  shown below.

Comment: [ERROR] 2018-08-07T22:43:32,666Z [main] errors.errorAndExit - Failed to create datasource.
Please check that the correct JDBC driver is installed in one of the following folders:
  - /apps/team/drivers/jdbc
Caused By net.corda.nodeapi.internal.persistence.MissingMigrationException: No migration defined for schema: net.corda.yo.YoState$YoSchema v1 
net.corda.nodeapi.internal.persistence.MissingMigrationException: No migration defined for schema: net.corda.yo.YoState$YoSchema v1
 at net.corda.nodeapi.internal.persistence.SchemaMigration.doRunMigration(SchemaMigration.kt:90) ...

Comment: See stackoverflow.com/questions/51744791.

Answer (score 0):

This issue was caused by an error in the host URL.